# ¿Cómo crear un ejecutable de multiples archivos python?

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

Soy principiante en estos temas por lo que hay muchas cosas que desconozco,
El ejecutable que deseo lograr está conformado por tres archivos .py y un png, escribí todo el código con spyder y lo probé en la consola de anaconda, después para hacerlo un .exe instale los paquetes de pyinstaller, sin embargo desconozco como lograr el exe, intente crear un exe del .py principal y como creí no funciono, luego intente crear un exe incluyendo los tres .py, de nuevo no funciono, si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería muchísimo.

Answer (score 0):

Es simple mira, si quieres que se genere solo un exe sin dependencia de carpetas ni nada tienes que usar la opción **--onefile**, para que tenga un icono específico es con **--icon="ruta/icono.ico"**, para que tenga un nombre específico es con **--name="nombre"** y al final colocas el nombre del archivo principal de python, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=img/img_C37.ico --name="Mi ejecutable" main.py
```

> **Nota:** Esto debes correrlo directamente desde la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo principal de python, nota que no es con python pyinstaller, es solamente pyinstaller en la consola

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya ví, me dice que el error por el que no se ejecuta es que no encuentra el archivo png, no sé cómo solucionarlo, quizá lo quite del código

Comment: Conviertelo a ico